# Slack API: Can I get all unread messages for a user?

Tags: slack-api

I develop a mobile app Speaking Email that reads emails out to the user, which can be used while driving to work for example. I would like to add Slack as an account type. Ideally we would have Speaking Email read out the user’s slack messages that are unread, as these will be what they need to catch up on. However it does not appear the Slack API has a method for retrieving the messages the user hasn’t read. Is this possible with the latest Slack API?

Comment: Looks like there's an undocumented endpoint `https://api.slack.com/api/client.counts?token=<your token here>` where each result entry has a `has_unreads` flag, and `latest` and `last_read` timestamps that could help in subsequent queries to [conversations.history](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history); still fiddling with it to confirm if it actually returns all data (including DMs, not just channels). Also seems to return some 'stale' data (very old channels with `has_unreads=true`) - but perhaps that's just my workspace (possibly never-read stuff from some archived channels)

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the same thing and found their API doc about Read Messages!

- https://api.slack.com/messaging/retrieving

Comment: This doesn’t tell you if a specific user (the one who gave you permission to install the app) has read the messages, let alone give you an easy way to query on latest unread messages. Also I believe this “channels” API is the old version of the API.